# ASCII art uncompression from a base-n number

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, base-conversion

This is inspired by an [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114226/76162) by [Magic Octupus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn).

Given two arguments, a positive integer and a string/list of characters:

1. Translate the number to base-n, where n is the length of the string.
2. For each character, replace every appearance of the index of that character in the base-n number with that character.
3. Print or return the new string.

#### Examples:

```
Input:
2740, ["|","_"]
2740 -> 101010110100 in base 2
     -> Replace 0s with "|" and 1s with "_"
Output: _|_|_|__|_||

Input:
698911, ["c","h","a","o"]
698911 ->  2222220133 in base 4
       ->  Replace 0s with "c", 1s with "h", 2s with "a", and 3s with "o"
Output -> "aaaaaachoo"

Input:
1928149325670647244912100789213626616560861130859431492905908574660758972167966, [" ","\n","|","_","-"]
Output:
    __   __    
   |  |_|  |   
___|       |___
-   -   -   -  
 - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -
_______________

Input: 3446503265645381015412, [':', '\n', '.', '_', '=', ' ', ')', '(', ',']
Output:
_===_
(.,.)
( : )
( : )
```

Rules:

- [IO is flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/76162).

  - You can take the number in any base, as long as it is consistent between inputs
  - The list of characters has to be 0-indexed though, where 0 is the first character and n-1 is the last
- Possible characters can be any printable ASCII, along with whitespace such as tabs and newlines
- The given list of characters will have a length in the range `2-10` inclusive. That is, the smallest base is binary and the largest is decimal (*no pesky letters here*)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/76162) are forbidden
- Feel free to answer even if your language can't handle the larger test cases.

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code for each language wins. (*I know all you golfing languages have one byte built-ins ready to go* ;)

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16490/76162) (deleted)

Comment: D'awwh, I feel honored. 05AB1E [tag:ascii-art] was my favorite awhile back.

Comment: you can create a new challenge: find the permutation of characters in the array to minimize the number :)

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gв¹sèJ
```

Since it was inspired by an 05AB1E answer, an answer given in 05AB1E seems fitting. :)

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna* by removing the foreach and doing this implicitly.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8//cKmskM7Kw@vsP//X0lJyYpLL95WQVNDB8jmMjYxMTM1MDYyMzUzMTW2MDQwNDUxNAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Fcw9CsJAEAXgfk8RUimozMzOryDpvEZQEe3sBCHeRxsLCw8QL@CN1g08eDx4fCC7PR4Lb8dnOf3e1/F1@z66ch8/XU0Z@kTGkA7n3SVpeCCmtm2bNPTL2gmDHDkyiRooGzEHEgKYB2FWUkUVBVfEDC7Bud4pQKIuY1Uw8TBCtVCd7HVa9ZtmPltMfmZWgUzVYMmOgMJIfw).

**Explanation:**

```python
g         # `l`: Take the length of the first (string) input
 в        # And then take the second input in base `l`
          # For each digit `y` of this base-converted number:
  ¹sè     #  Push the `y`'th character of the first input
     J    # Join everything together (and output implicitly)
```

Comment: `gв¹sèJ` to save a byte.

Comment: @Emigna Thanks. Can't believe I hadn't thought about `¹sè` myself now.. (I knew changing the `?` to a `J` would give the same output in this case.)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/), 49 bytes

Cannot comment yet, so I post the Python 2 answer adapted to Python 3.5.

```
f=lambda n,s:n and f(n//len(s),s)+s[n%len(s)]or''
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Feel free to include a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##PZDdasMwDIXv@xQmMJJQb7X8I9uBPMCu9gCpKdna0ELnhDi9GOzdMzmFXegDHdnSkaaf5TpGta5De@@/P889izw1kfXxzIYqHg73S6xSzVO9T118eWZhnMtyXS5pSW3XSasFZ13xW/DiVITAO/TOA2Tti7QrRU8xbjXw0oH2Shq0ArWVWnuQIIR1XoJCiQhoUDgEUMIZrxU9l14YT5nViMIa560EtB4xD2HU/BgJTwe8eN0mKa3RCCWpmzbKgQCjQdKHsik5K48x8y3jlNFmsIw6o8rgZQhhN4xzvgq7Rbbt3OzYNN/iUhXvcXosDc2ncv2vfjyWTSZPe7phvl32V69/) to help showcase your solution.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, <s>72</s> 50 bytes

```java
a->n->n.toString(a.length).chars().map(c->a[c-48])
```

-22 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* by returning an `IntStream` instead of printing directly.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fVFNa@MwEL3nVwyGBQlsIcmybG23gbZsYQ97yjEJQavaiVNHNpbSJbT97amcuPSDUtBhNG/mvXkzW/2gk@3d/dE02jn4q2v7OAFwXvvawDagZO/rhlR7a3zdWnI7Br/MRvfzZfxtzQnbab8h1/X6j/Xluuzfdzjfl3pHAjI7RdMpVHAJR51MbXjEtyFf2zXSpCnt2m8wGWQdwoG1QyaZ6rlJRLHEx4tJGLvb/2vC2OP0D219B7vgCJ1Z5kvQeHAH4EvnUfS0imKIeC5ohC/e5YNGOyBSFYqxjxgs7NMqGVCmeMGESnkmcypFzoVQjDNK80JxlkouJZOZpIVkLKVFpkQayrmimQq/XEhJ86xQOWcyV1J@lPm5sGR1CRjFg1QqhMxoygOdyNKCUZYJxs8dz5O3e50cnwjOjsHFMEZ2dF4R3XXNAbmw3Juwy6u@1weE8Zi25X/46mrIhpKq7X9rsxn2Pjs4X@5Iu/ekC/y@QtEPE8UGjy4@441F0cK@Tvx8fAE).

**Explanation:**

```java
a->n->                  // Method with char-array and BigInteger parameters
  n.toString(a.length)  //  Convert the input-number to Base `amount_of_characters`
   .chars()             //  Loop over it's digits (as characters)
   .map(c->a[c          //   Convert each character to the `i`'th character of the input
              -48])     //   by first converting the digit-character to index-integer `i`
```

Comment: `a->n->n.toString(a.length).chars().map(c->a[c-48])` (50 bytes) since "IO is flexible"

Comment: `String f(char[]a,int n){return n>0?f(a,n/a.length)+a[n%a.length]:"";}` (69 bytes) recursive one, for the fun.

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, 2 bytes

Can take the second input as an array or a string. Fails the last 2 test cases as the numbers exceed JavaScript's max integer. Replace `s` with `ì` to output an array of characters instead.

```
sV
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=c1Y=&input=Njk4OTExClsiYyIsImgiLCJhIiwibyJd)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```hs
0!_=[]
n!l=cycle l!!n:div n(length l)!l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30Ax3jY6litPMcc2uTI5J1UhR1Exzyols0whTyMnNS@9JEMhR1Mx539uYmaegq1CQWlJcEmRgoqCmaWFpaGholJyRmK@0n8A)

As Haskell's `Int` type is limited to `9223372036854775807`, this fails for larger numbers.

-1 byte thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni).

### Ungolfed

```hs
(!) :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]

0 ! _ = []  -- If the number is 0, we reached the end. Base case: empty string
n ! l = 
  let newN = (n `div` length l) in   -- divide n by the base
    cycle l!!n                       -- return the char encoded by the LSD ... 
    : newN!l                         -- ... prepended to the rest of the output (computed recursively)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZA7a8MwFIV3/4qj0MGG2iRLaQzpkHYJlC4ZQ2hs@SYWkSUjyQn@9e61WujSatDjPr57jtrKX0nraUpFhrLEzgTkLzi8tpU7/t6SZAmBT2xwOAJ5jt0ZoSWYoavJQXksH3EnOKpkS03MkWkKbCtPkLyVoK4PI3xwylwSwzjNuATQFGDo/sGv1ODUqNuJY@YSWugMyiAO5LBqeCDqMdJrZnIzIEepCVqIufCvxc2OwuBM7JNsh6VJ27DMH9b7/g1FUSDyyihGaOB/3lzcO@rZ4mzWRoojH2C//8UOoR8CUmk7PrnGkRycVzfSYzZ1FbvagDP74PCAp/XzerUSC9ZmF9MX)

Comment: Nice idea to use `cycle` instead of `mod`! `div n(length l)` saves a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
YA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9Lx/38jcxMDLvWaeHUA)

Inputs are a number and a string.

Fails for numbers exceeding `2^53`, because of floating-point precision.

#### Explanation

What do `YA` know, a builtin (base conversion with specified target symbols).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(c)(n)`, where **c** is a list of characters and **n** is an integer.

Safe only for **n < 2<sup>53</sup>**.

```javascript
c=>n=>n.toString(c.length).replace(/./g,i=>c[i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYpBCsIwEADvPiOnLNStFVF7SD/hsRQJa5pGwm5JQ0/@PcarMHOaedvdbpTCmo8sL1dmU8gMXMEsj5wCe00YHfu8ACa3RktOt9j6JpiBxjBBIeFNosMoXs96VB/VqKeaQJ9vlxPA4b9T7UvVVuX3Xft733UA5Qs)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

#### *With support for big integers*

Takes input in currying syntax `(c)(a)`, where **c** is a list of characters and **a** is a list of decimal digits (as integers).

```javascript
c=>g=(a,p=0,b=c.length,r=0)=>1/a[p]?g(a.map((d,i)=>(r=d+r*10,d=r/b|0,r%=b,d|i-p||p++,d)),p)+c[r]:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7LTsMwEEX3fAWKhGITN/X4MY4rufwBPxAi5DyaFrVJ5BZW@fdgXl2w6eJYmpHP3PvmP/y5CYfpshrGtlt2bmnctnfEs8lxVrsmP3ZDf9mz4Dh1W1j7cqqeeuLzk58IadkhbklwbRYegbPWhXU9cxYeXM3a@bCa5nnKMtZSyiaaNWWoNmm6NONwHo9dfhx7siNlMicseU0qSso8z1NhFE@r74Dn91PdBUrp3X@lico@4iPjVUVbWICb8n2UXob4/ASzZHW9AFYUoKwUGg1HZYRSFgRwbgorQKJABNTICwSQvNBWyfhdWK5tnIxC5EYX1ghAYxFvVtn8Vcl/q7jIVz8aIRF2rSaVQs2liPFKywI4aAXif8LyCQ)

Answer (score 4):

## x86 32-bit machine code (32-bit integers): 17 bytes.

(also see other versions below, including 16 bytes for 32-bit or 64-bit, with a DF=1 calling convention.)

Caller passes args in registers, including a pointer to the *end* of an output buffer (like [my C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166708/ascii-art-uncompression-from-a-base-n-number/166831#166831); see it for justification and explanation of the algorithm.)  [glibc's internal `_itoa` does this](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/generic/_itoa.h.html#39), so it's not just contrived for code-golf.  The arg-passing registers are close to x86-64 System V, except we have an arg in EAX instead of EDX.

On return, EDI points to the first byte of a 0-terminated C string in the output buffer.  The usual return-value register is EAX/RAX, but in assembly language you can use whatever calling convention is convenient for a function.  (`xchg eax,edi` at the end would add 1 byte).

The caller can calculate an explicit length if it wants, from `buffer_end - edi`.  But I don't think we can justify omitting the terminator unless the function actually returns both start+end pointers or pointer+length.  That would save 3 bytes in this version, but I don't think it's justifiable.

- EAX = n = number to decode.  (For `idiv`.  The other args aren't implicit operands.)
- EDI = end of output buffer  (64-bit version still uses `dec edi`, so must be in the low 4GiB)
- ESI/RSI = lookup table, aka LUT.  not clobbered.
- ECX = length of table = base. not clobbered.

`nasm -felf32 ascii-compress-base.asm -l /dev/stdout | cut -b -30,$((30+10))-` (Hand edited to shrink comments, line numbering is weird.)

```
   32-bit: 17 bytes        ;  64-bit: 18 bytes
                           ; same source assembles as 32 or 64-bit
 3                         %ifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elf32
 5                         %define rdi edi
 6   address               %define rsi esi
11          machine        %endif
14          code           %define DEF(funcname) funcname: global funcname
16          bytes           
22                         ;;; returns: pointer in RDI to the start of a 0-terminated string
24                         ;;; clobbers:; EDX (tmp remainder)
25                         DEF(ascii_compress_nostring)
27 00000000 C60700             mov     BYTE [rdi], 0
28                         .loop:                    ; do{
29 00000003 99                 cdq                    ; 1 byte shorter than   xor edx,edx / div
30 00000004 F7F9               idiv    ecx            ; edx=n%B   eax=n/B
31                         
32 00000006 8A1416             mov     dl, [rsi + rdx]   ; dl = LUT[n%B]
33 00000009 4F                 dec     edi               ; --output  ; 2B in x86-64
34 0000000A 8817               mov     [rdi], dl         ; *output = dl
35                         
36 0000000C 85C0               test    eax,eax           ; div/idiv don't write flags in practice, and the manual says they're undefined.
37 0000000E 75F3               jnz     .loop         ; }while(n);
38                         
39 00000010 C3                 ret
           0x11 bytes = 17
40 00000011 11             .size: db $ - .start
```

It's surprising that the simplest version with basically no speed/size tradeoffs is the smallest, but `std`/`cld` cost 2 bytes to use `stosb` to go in descending order and still follow the common DF=0 calling convention.  (And STOS decrements *after* storing, leaving the pointer pointing one byte too low on loop exit, costing us extra bytes to work around.)

## Versions:

I came up with 4 significantly different implementation tricks (using simple `mov` load/store (above), using `lea`/`movsb` (neat but not optimal), using `xchg`/`xlatb`/`stosb`/`xchg`, and one that enters the loop with an overlapping-instruction hack. See code below).  The last needs a trailing `0` in the lookup table to copy as the output string terminator, so I'm counting that as +1 byte.  Depending on 32/64-bit (1-byte `inc` or not), and whether we can assume the caller sets DF=1 (`stosb` descending) or whatever, different versions are (tied for) shortest.

DF=1 to store in descending order makes it a win to xchg / stosb / xchg, but the caller often won't want that; It feels like offloading work to the caller in a hard-to-justify way.  (Unlike custom arg-passing and return-value registers, which typically don't cost an asm caller any extra work.)  But in 64-bit code, `cld` / `scasb` works as `inc rdi`, avoiding truncating the output pointer to 32-bit, so it's sometimes inconvenient to preserve DF=1 in 64-bit-clean functions.  .  (Pointers to static code/data are 32-bit in x86-64 non-PIE executables on Linux, and always in the Linux x32 ABI, so an x86-64 version using 32-bit pointers is usable in some cases.)  Anyway, this interaction makes it interesting to look at different combinations of requirements.

- **IA32 with a DF=0 on entry/exit calling convention: 17B (`nostring`)**.
- IA32: **16B (with a DF=1 convention: `stosb_edx_arg` or `skew`)**; or with incoming DF=dontcare, leaving it set: **16+1B `stosb_decode_overlap`** or 17B `stosb_edx_arg`
- **x86-64 with 64-bit pointers, and a DF=0 on entry/exit calling convention: 17+1 bytes (`stosb_decode_overlap`)**, 18B (`stosb_edx_arg` or `skew`)
- x86-64 with 64-bit pointers, other DF handling: **16B (DF=1 `skew`)**, 17B (`nostring` with DF=1, using `scasb` instead of `dec`).  18B (`stosb_edx_arg` preserving DF=1 with 3-byte `inc rdi`).

  Or if we allow returning a pointer to 1 byte before the string, **15B** (`stosb_edx_arg` without the `inc` at the end).  **All set to call again and expand another string into the buffer with different base / table...**  But that would make more sense if we didn't store a terminating `0` either, and you might put the function body inside a loop so that's really a separate problem.
- x86-64 with 32-bit output pointer, DF=0 calling convention: no improvement over 64-bit output pointer, but 18B (`nostring`) ties now.
- x86-64 with 32-bit output pointer: no improvement over the best 64-bit pointer versions, so 16B (DF=1 `skew`).  Or to set DF=1 and leave it, 17B for `skew` with `std` but not `cld`.  Or 17+1B for `stosb_decode_overlap` with `inc edi` at the end instead of `cld`/`scasb`.

---

## With a DF=1 calling convention: 16 bytes (IA32 or x86-64)

Requires DF=1 on input, leaves it set.  [Barely plausible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/165020#165020), at least on a per-function basis.  Does the same thing as the above version, but with xchg to get the remainder in/out of AL before/after XLATB (table lookup with R/EBX as base) and STOSB (`*output-- = al`).

With a normal DF=0 on entry/exit convention, **the `std` / `cld`/`scasb` version is 18 bytes for 32 and 64-bit code, and is 64-bit clean** (works with a 64-bit output pointer).

Note that the input args are in different registers, including RBX for the table (for `xlatb`).  Also note that this loop starts by storing AL, and ends with the last char not stored yet (hence the `mov` at the end).  So the loop is "skewed" relative to the others, hence the name.

```
                            ;DF=1 version.  Uncomment std/cld for DF=0
                            ;32-bit and 64-bit: 16B
157                         DEF(ascii_compress_skew)
158                         ;;; inputs
159                             ;; O in RDI = end of output buffer
160                             ;; I in RBX = lookup table  for xlatb
161                             ;; n in EDX = number to decode
162                             ;; B in ECX = length of table = modulus
163                         ;;; returns: pointer in RDI to the start of a 0-terminated string
164                         ;;; clobbers:; EDX=0, EAX=last char
165                         .start:
166                         ;    std
167 00000060 31C0               xor    eax,eax
168                         .loop:                    ; do{
169 00000062 AA                 stosb
170 00000063 92                 xchg    eax, edx
171                         
172 00000064 99                 cdq                    ; 1 byte shorter than   xor edx,edx / div
173 00000065 F7F9               idiv    ecx            ; edx=n%B   eax=n/B
174                         
175 00000067 92                 xchg    eax, edx       ; eax=n%B   edx=n/B
176 00000068 D7                 xlatb                  ; al = byte [rbx + al]
177                         
178 00000069 85D2               test    edx,edx
179 0000006B 75F5               jnz     .loop         ; }while(n = n/B);
180                         
181 0000006D 8807               mov     [rdi], al     ; stosb would move RDI away
182                         ;    cld
183 0000006F C3                 ret

184 00000070 10             .size: db $ - .start
```

A similar non-skewed version overshoots EDI/RDI and then fixes it up.

```
                            ; 32-bit DF=1: 16B    64-bit: 17B (or 18B for DF=0)
70                         DEF(ascii_compress_stosb_edx_arg)  ; x86-64 SysV arg passing, but returns in RDI
71                             ;; O in RDI = end of output buffer
72                             ;; I in RBX = lookup table  for xlatb
73                             ;; n in EDX = number to decode
74                             ;; B in ECX = length of table
75                         ;;; clobbers EAX,EDX, preserves DF
76                             ; 32-bit mode: a DF=1 convention would save 2B (use inc edi instead of cld/scasb)
77                             ; 32-bit mode: call-clobbered DF would save 1B (still need STD, but INC EDI saves 1)
79                         .start:
80 00000040 31C0               xor     eax,eax
81                         ;    std
82 00000042 AA                 stosb
83                         .loop:
84 00000043 92                 xchg    eax, edx
85 00000044 99                 cdq
86 00000045 F7F9               idiv    ecx            ; edx=n%B   eax=n/B
87                         
88 00000047 92                 xchg    eax, edx       ; eax=n%B   edx=n/B
89 00000048 D7                 xlatb                  ; al = byte [rbx + al]
90 00000049 AA                 stosb                  ; *output-- = al
91                         
92 0000004A 85D2               test    edx,edx
93 0000004C 75F5               jnz     .loop
94                         
95 0000004E 47                 inc    edi
96                             ;; cld
97                             ;; scasb          ; rdi++
98 0000004F C3                 ret
99 00000050 10             .size: db $ - .start
    16 bytes for the 32-bit DF=1 version
```

I tried an alternate version of this with  `lea esi, [rbx+rdx]` / `movsb` as the inner loop body.  (RSI is reset every iteration, but RDI decrements).  But it can't use xor-zero / stos for the terminator, so it's 1 byte larger.  (And it's not 64-bit clean for the lookup table without a REX prefix on the LEA.)

---

## LUT with explicit length *and* a 0 terminator: 16+1 bytes (32-bit)

This version sets DF=1 and leaves it that way.  I'm counting the extra LUT byte required as part of the total byte count.

The cool trick here is **having the same bytes decode two different ways**.  We fall into the middle of the loop with remainder = base and quotient= input number, and copy the 0 terminator into place.

On the first time through the function, the first 3 bytes of the loop are consumed as the high bytes of a disp32 for an LEA.  That LEA copies the base (modulus) to EDX, `idiv` produces the remainder for later iterations.

The 2nd byte of `idiv ebp` is `FD`, which is the opcode for the `std` instruction that this function needs to work.  (This was a lucky discovery.  I had been looking at this with `div` earlier, which distinguishes itself from `idiv` using the `/r` bits in ModRM.  The 2nd byte of `div epb` decodes as `cmc`, which is harmless but not helpful.  But with `idiv ebp` can we actually remove the `std` from the top of the function.)

Note the input registers are difference once again: EBP for the base.

```
103                         DEF(ascii_compress_stosb_decode_overlap)
104                         ;;; inputs
105                             ;; n in EAX = number to decode
106                             ;; O in RDI = end of output buffer
107                             ;; I in RBX = lookup table, 0-terminated.  (first iter copies LUT[base] as output terminator)
108                             ;; B in EBP = base = length of table
109                         ;;; returns: pointer in RDI to the start of a 0-terminated string
110                         ;;; clobbers: EDX (=0), EAX,  DF
111                             ;; Or a DF=1 convention allows idiv ecx (STC).  Or we could put xchg after stos and not run IDIV's modRM
112                         .start:
117                             ;2nd byte of div ebx = repz.  edx=repnz.
118                             ;            div ebp = cmc.   ecx=int1 = icebp (hardware-debug trap)
119                             ;2nd byte of idiv ebp = std = 0xfd.  ecx=stc
125                         
126                             ;lea    edx, [dword 0 + ebp]
127 00000040 8D9500             db  0x8d, 0x95, 0   ; opcode, modrm, 0 for lea edx, [rbp+disp32].  low byte = 0 so DL = BPL+0 = base
128                             ; skips xchg, cdq, and idiv.
129                             ; decode starts with the 2nd byte of idiv ebp, which decodes as the STD we need
130                         .loop:
131 00000043 92                 xchg    eax, edx
132 00000044 99                 cdq
133 00000045 F7FD               idiv    ebp            ; edx=n%B   eax=n/B;
134                             ;; on loop entry, 2nd byte of idiv ebp runs as STD.  n in EAX, like after idiv.  base in edx (fake remainder)
135                         
136 00000047 92                 xchg    eax, edx       ; eax=n%B   edx=n/B
137 00000048 D7                 xlatb                  ; al = byte [rbx + al]
138                         .do_stos:
139 00000049 AA                 stosb                  ; *output-- = al
140                         
141 0000004A 85D2               test    edx,edx
142 0000004C 75F5               jnz     .loop
143                         
144                         %ifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elf32
145 0000004E 47                 inc     edi         ; saves a byte in 32-bit.  Makes DF call-clobbered instead of normal DF=0
146                         %else
147                             cld
148                             scasb          ; rdi++
149                         %endif
150                         
151 0000004F C3                 ret
152 00000050 10             .size: db $ - .start
153 00000051 01                     db 1   ; +1 because we require an extra LUT byte
       # 16+1 bytes for a 32-bit version.
       # 17+1 bytes for a 64-bit version that ends with DF=0
```

This overlapping decode trick can also be used with `cmp eax, imm32`: it only takes 1 byte to effectively jump forward 4 bytes, only clobbering flags.  (This is terrible for performance on CPUs that mark instruction boundaries in L1i cache, BTW.)

But here, we're using 3 bytes to copy a register and jump into the loop.  That would normally take 2+2 (mov + jmp), and would let us jump into the loop right before the STOS instead of before the XLATB.  But then we'd need a separate STD, and it wouldn't be very interesting.

[Try it online! (with a `_start` caller that uses `sys_write` on the result)](https://tio.run/##zVlrbxpLEv3OryhFGxliwGB7vYkRH0Ls3IuUxJHt3M0q10I9Mw10PA8yPWMgu/vbs6eqZ2Bw8ONubrRryfIMVFfX45yq6rayVkdeuGzFykbfvj01YxPENBqdfbh8/@Fy9Prs/O3Ly9GoSTocH@zXeoPh5QXh4WmgxybWlAaGdGDW7xbvtvKuFqTVYv3u4d2rvPt49yvvAd4DvOs4MONajfDT69EkTDwV0jM1znT6jLKpplB5OiSTUZRA0mhLxpKKSS9mOjWRjjMsGGuV5aleqT85fV0f57Efq0g3qHw6LvWXH9RqLKisb8zIT6JZqq0dxYnNUhNPGrUeLDLxLM9saV@Mdzp9@ZH6FOeRp1PKEgq0nwS6FDljkfOTIUTgGyVjSvIMOsjLx2MsoHqUW7xplguTOaLcKNcOZe0Frw2T5DqfUaa8cKV6ILu/4t1DHU@yKWt3EmxqqhGD2B7TLDEx4lcaAhM5kDZTacYrFHVa@Doyscp0QM5b0eAjPHDKHvfo9ORjP1Qw1J@qtMk@9zu1tug4Fnui5Ib/0OAfl6f0Cfi4ahIkYPfsmLb89ChI/ikr/eDLdoEuecsMhk6TlM3Ppkgz0SJJGSpN/NIeBeZGlBg88F@AalMJxPrx0wF/pfC0N6htmBuETVgL9O4yBq@cYSEi@ubD5Sesu6r1WMxmgYu69ZX15BFpFg2gwXeWt1pFkov3LAXCEF1LR4ctD@AtUmI3bCmihu3Xmp4Vivr42FkOLaIX7jSZYvz8Of4q8hLuyup/z6cm1PW40XNrAQkkzXwF9AOP/kItcims1VABkC4VmklM3aNtPICV1mv8ecjfBPng4y2Qiwd1HykHNVS8hO2TJpZm1Hgk/kv0splN4LdJ7IhOb5CGk9dUt4qfuqLlYF/SgpoCHo5proHOeCdrPAzxItIwdCej3OpxHoZs7CxUvgZmjRQoKFSpdiJgFy386YS9mk91qlFkrYtaCTNBGd1BG@AOez@WWn@QHW08vg7VxFIeu@IZtB12Qq0c3q1hyniLXSFMr4xdCWlK4nBZxmubFwD1WauFpA0dwX4U1H54R9C4WrtY3Yv9sue8fDP85d0d4LdZYr0RojVS6aTBqhfPj1pHh3SxtL8htROaKcuZdRAtSm9BgD@LEGNUvkWoMm@ThCf3kfCHOOKUVMlxjG5x8rrfJT@Jb9BrTRLTPMlDtA2wifYHVAcHJO5cF01sM63EVWRpTzLU2KbVV2HYKoxBDwI9K1pB0brNTBhSrPHlxeWJi/Lw3St4P6SCyKXiosQKl@cGHt8C6LHzYHMHgCIFyqAbtAyYyFTq36gB3H1uAxWsdTvHSSYmwkjOVRkq@MacX4esWAVIFSx2qrkmFKplGPrvGFzbqmwtr1bygZMXcYbVNqoq7oXShpny6JIqvFqbv5XcDtTCcHW7ZxV9e12ozM2euCblluapwU5jqT9A1sX1MlTXuifzSqTiHNZYtbT8vtxB4azUqO8qRjFEMhRdl76vWPS4TOzuPtAkH1EiHPtGyY1OQzX7OTPjA4WiuTHPoaDXxyZF/A0PUX4y45mZpxtPWX1FypbKyzVJeqvDDt4zBiD98wdNqWb1fqchI2aTVkUIQUm31B5QK5lbxw6mRv3i8lUDLkMYLdcXhrNvrt/yKUKAKxxntmIuo@HJ8Lcdy/Xi/O0G13urqa9gfZX0vc8RmlI7SCTxBdj2oVbIAm/FJFCmz8PA17bjGx7jr@2iUFV@nPAMwn7ktx3P@whmF58Yn7@pY@4O5hgiWoH28glGSobXd7uatSYuS33qLMaMAdZnM7@wE7juLDwl40uvHG2YnGSi6GBfykRmyeHmQJRbyTkfwIRbsgpqoOfwebPUVihkbenRYRPK0CLJXpuZ5VTJ@rlaMjI4arBrgOREZjLNGIhzDRnEuvVVp8keAlyjO396Rc2SCq/C/oCVhgmaDV46PHPxHEKfcbjCMVEaqIiaaBYa32StAskOhWUCiyFHQvEpmCdpAI92OaCu6jmPnwfs8Yu/uvGvR8mM2dtkCKURf8jVn1U5Pak32w2MnR3sX8FjPuNJtpAbsgmdvMHT4P2b3U7BsgIdLmoM3CZ3gaZgltNbwsfVDEcv65zj@G5DQ5MwM/nTYonlWLModzvQhFvWH29E3uyBRtQrmZvEAhrUsixdNrcayEQUs2ASYlTWyCaF5loXxBXfyRUifM19pD5GewC/ImXQCVC3fn7vKxl//MNdcFvLeugiRjIQf3/w7BVDkHL2rk40iNdbhEgOPLdmrMpsFidpBGdRXDuYhsvDyAOtsnpVc2fLXNU3D6d5XruLQ732Fc9Xc87cl9yk2t3foKJxXxIPHuq113q@rbf@f03Y@AQVIQ9z@3PuYzruHmZ1LbNqXhtXFrd612OOjW403VoK/nc3Nj@V1Y/j55ZDKANjb1AeRW/d5KiwJKeUCXfggIyWvCt0Qpeqkml30uibkGAkL40aZl6Vh3zKDCu7Sq8BSKsf@fhIoBhXjvCpHODl46vq0R4243MQBmTZffH8qrCdy/UKYoxZBqvjE6rLxVSc8lDNY02LolSzSAlhPvp0uAc4/GN0cD7zPEB33LVWfdhIN6cPipkZhBHbYgYsWh9qESxCi9ly3qpesyHnTQ5BdQtukHwbXdLmHgu3Tfm1u6VRp4S5cmGOThAE/HmlMFXYTX8vJ1Y5k3IMpboJWG5UmGsuFROdFdfdGGMy2phiiquruYqz1bVNzxnGVbIIYDrhLPK1iHM498rk7xcxlmNYvUHjNImQWlRFXSlRMMKfav9absnQrXBu85M0zWeY5HSUpMvaHQNb6fIKMovF5a@no4vL8@G7X37vLHiPmH7vsCDvcthxk@dd@kxbt@@HXftxHbXClvKcWOHUYec2HA/d/qN35yMJ1QaW8H236NNcTTAtdtbFgZd3V2WZhfm/IqU0y5YVY2lHemGyeqdR3l@8HAwr3blAM3M5fYzN3Xts5tw7q7CtwwttQKHb5JyMisbF6hsCg9raFeioxo733D9wPX/Em7Izo0maoNk6XO3lNt3DLBPmgd5TNtrLYwPyjY4O29MttqxD4rQgMKsRxGpfToPtNAlUpmrFv3XcCdXdbKMwwtEvOe3/DbGRb45lLHnyr9GTIqwrmaMXz190uxtSr359efak3FCahZRVEedCvf7HDJ@t2Nwn6/P0k/JWyFs@qp6sHaq64ypzzf05psxEfOvV6fCOO4sdFySkyGKhKxeRjH6AjlZ2ueYt08Rxsb2iltMGxon9tW//AQ)

It's best for debugging to run it under `strace`, or hexdump the output, so you can see verify that there's a `\0` terminator in the right place and so on.  But you can see this actually work, and produce `AAAAAACHOO` for an input of

```
num  equ 698911
table:  db "CHAO"
%endif
    tablen equ $ - table
    db 0  ; "terminator" needed by ascii_compress_stosb_decode_overlap
```

(Actually `xxAAAAAACHOO\0x\0\0...`, because we're dumping from 2 bytes earlier in the buffer out to a fixed length.  So we can see that the function wrote the bytes it was supposed to and *didn't* step on any bytes it shouldn't have.  The start-pointer passed to the function was the 2nd-last `x` character, which was followed by zeros.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ṙ1ṃ@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYoxCgJRDAWvIr92IclPXpLOe6hYbSOLvWDnKTzKHmdPElPMwMA81217Vx37j4/9e6mq6ziN87i9Wp/m0SzjXpwSrDnF4AR1UU0WJvJI4QkBGAYKME8KS529S5JllytAbpEuDE/gDw)

`ṃ` is literally a built-in for this. The other three bytes account for Jelly's one-based indexing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does Jelly even have the builtin `ṃ` "_Base decompression; convert x to base length(y) then index into y._"? Is it for the very exceptional cases where the base you ant to convert to and length of a string/integer/list are equal? When I search for it, I can only find three answers using it: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151507/52210); [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156292/52210); [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118735/52210). Kinda a weird builtin in every day code-golf challenges imo. :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it's very useful when you want, for example, to convert **N** to hexadecimal using hex letters instead of a list of numbers.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It's a compression method for strings. In the first example the string desired is `“sspspdspdspfdspfdsp”`, but with `“çƥ÷£ḟ’ṃ“spdf”¤` you save six bytes. It's especially useful with Jelly's base 250 numbers

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Jo King</sup>

```python
f=lambda n,s:n and f(n/len(s),s)+s[n%len(s)]or''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDdasMwDIXv@xQmMJJQb7P8I9uBPMCu9gCpKena0ELnhDi9GOzdMzmFXegDHdnSkaaf5TpGua5De@@/T@eeRZ6ayPp4ZkMV3@@XWKWap3qfuvjyzMI4l@W6XNKS2q6TVgvOuuK34MWxCIF36J0HyNoXaVeKnmLcauClA@2VNGgFaiu19iBBCOu8BIUSEdCgcAighDNeK3ouvTCeMqsRhTXOWwloPWIewqj5IRKeDnjxuk1SWqMRSlI3bZQDAUaDpA9lU3JWHmLmW8Yxo81gGXVGlcHLEMJuGOd8FHaLbNu52bFpvsWFFR9xeiwNzafyv/j5WDaVLO3pgvl02d76Bw)

#### Alternative version (won't finish for large numbers), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Jo King</sup>

```python
f=lambda n,s:s*n and f(n/len(s),s)+(s*n)[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9LasMwEIb3OYUQhNiN2mr0GEkGH6CrHsA2xm1iEkjHxlIWhdzdlbPobv4Hw//Nv@kykVrXsb4NP1@ngZGIVXwhNtCJjQW9385UxFLE8lhku2yoW9M5plg3jXJGCsYfPe9Eg8EHgCy/L8O0GdoYtFIrtGis9iDBGlCCHaqW3vqalYU45BoE5cEErSw6icYpYwIokNL5oECjQoT8QnoE0NLbYHSuqyBtyMoZROmsD04BuoCYB7CWHv0r77rdOC0bD7sSe26udmxerpQY/6D5nirGBQm@X/g@/ief9/SMWuLHzL@B83yvfw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>3</s> 1 bytes

```
⍘θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfQ1LT@/z/a2MTEzNTA2MjM1MzE1NjC0MDQ1MTQSEchWt1KXUdBPSYPROqBiHgQYQsiFECEJojQABE66rGx/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only. Previous version before the builtin was added, 8 bytes:

```
⭆↨θＬη§ηι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcXBCsIwDADQX8mtCURZ13aI4kFvgoLgcQ4ps6yDUXUW8e@rubzXRz/3Dz@Vcp7HlPGS/w0n/8S9fwd8MRxDGnLESMSwy4d0D1@MDCMRbUppjbWNq0zduMY6s9KVdlbXDK1aKwZ1TeJSuAlbAQQSUGDVdWXxmX4) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    η       Second input
   Ｌ        Length
  θ         First input
 ↨          Base convert to array
⭆           Map over values and join
      η     Second input
       ι    Current value
     §      Index into list
            Implicitly print result
```

Comment: Actually it's supposed to already work but evidently I've messed up yet again >_>

Comment: Also, it would actually be [1 byte](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfQ1LT@/z/a2MTEzNTA2MjM1MzE1NjC0MDQ1MTQSEfBzCj2v25ZTiIA) :P (it's currently broken though, so i'm not using number and string array as arguments) (also, i wonder how (un)useful implicit input is)

Comment: @ASCII-only Don't you mean "1 bytes" (see your -vl output ;-) Also, implicit input would seem to be almost useless in Charcoal, except for challenges like this.

Comment: [:D](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfQ1LT@/z/a2MTEzNTA2MjM1MzE1NjC0MDQ1MTQSEchWt1KXUdBPSYPROqBiHgQYQsiFECEJojQABE66rGx/3XLchIB)

Comment: @ASCII-only Still "1 bytes" though :P

Comment: @ASCII-only Plural "bytes" instead of singular "byte" is what Neil means. ;) As for your 1-byte answer, why the crossed-out `θη`? Looks a bit confusing tbh. Why not just remove it completely and leave `⍘`?

Comment: (also yeah crap i meant to fix that as well but forgot >_> i guess i'll fix it later. it works fine in the post generator but not here)

Comment: Doesn't this answer not count since the built-in was added after the question?

Comment: @Nit I double-checked and the built-in had been added before the question was asked, but I hadn't realised because it had a bug.

Answer (score 3):

### C++, <s>150</s> 144 bytes, `uint64` input

-6 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<string>
using s=std::string;s u(uint64_t n,s b){s t;for(;n;n/=b.size())t=std::to_string(n%b.size())+t;for(auto&a:t)a=b[a-48];return t;}
```

Using a variable to store the size would increase the bytecount by 1

To call the function :

```cpp
u(2740, "|_")
```

First the number, second is the string ( char array )

Test cases :

```cpp
std::cout << u(2740, "|_") << '\n' << u(698911, "chao") << '\n';
return 0;
```

Comment: 3 bytes to shave off: You don't need the space after `#include`, you can change `;;` to just `;`, and `'0'` can just be `48`

Comment: Also, the while loop could be a `for` loop: `for(;n;n/=b.size())t=std::to_string(n%b.size())+t;`

Comment: @ceilingcat, I forgot that `b.size()` doesn't change in that loop.

Comment: @ceilingcat That would increase the bytecount by 1, instead of lowering it

Answer (score 3):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 112 bytes

```d
import std.conv;C u(C,I)(I n,C b){C t;for(I l=b.length;n;n/=l)t=to!C(n%l)~t;foreach(ref c;t)c=b[c-48];return t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc7BagIxEAbgs/sUo1CYgXVbi1gl7CknoUdvIiWbjd1ATCQ7sQe7ffVtKi3Uw1zm//hn2nG0p3OIDD23lQ7@IiQklOWWcAu@lNDQVQKLY4h54eqmcsa/cye88I@1I645TCX6B0dfN2WU7jCaI2jBpOtmr@fL9UFEwyn6XDSMKnEA1etOxR53hDvQBFf4E2GKP9H@QKhJwFAUl2BbOCnrMbti8u/hPDaIYvIRLRvnMeHzy/IpvZYw@3ybVb9HiO7IarPeLBY3lONwx4bxGw)

This is a port of [HatsuPointerKun's C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166852/55550)

The calling style is `u(ulong(n), to!(char[])(b))`, where `n` and `b` are the left and right arguments

### D specific stuff

Sadly, we need to import `std.conv` to do any type conversions above **very** basic type conversion.

Using the golfy template system, and giving the function the required types (which is why calling it is not just `u(n,b)`), we can shorten occurrences of `char[]` and `ulong` to `1` byte each, when inside f the function.

D initializes our types for us, so `C t;` is short for `C t=cast(char[])([])`

`to!C` converts the integer `n%l` to a character array (using codepoints), and `~` is concatenation

`foreach(ref c;t)` is like C++'s `for(... : ...)` loop, but a little longer. `ref` is like `&`, it treats `c` as copied-by-reference (i.e., we can modify `t`). Luckily, D infers the type of `c` without *any* keyword denoting type.

Comment: [I golfed your TIO bits :P](https://tio.run/##Vc7BagIxEAbgs/sUo1CYgXVbi1gl7CknoUdvIiWbjd1ATCQ7sQe7ffVtKi3Uw1zm//hn2nG0p3OIDD23lQ7@IiQklOWWcAu@lNDQVQKLY4h54eqmcsa/cye88I@1I645TCX6B0dfN2WU7jCaI2jBpOtmr@fL9UFEwyn6XDSMKnEA1etOxR53hDvQBFf4E2GKP9H@QKhJwFAUl2BbOCnrMbti8u/hPDaIYvIRLRvnMeHzy/IpvZYw@3ybVb9HiO7IarPeLBY3lONwx4bxGw "D – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>14 13</s> 12 bytes

```apl
⊢⌷⍨∘⊂⊥⍣¯1⍨∘≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXECWWxCQZWhkYf7/UdeiRz3bH/WueNQx41FX06OupY96Fx9abwgV6Vz0Pw2o9FFvH0R/V/Oh9caP2iYCecFBzkAyxMMz@L@RuYmBQpoCkOsV7O@nrlQTr6TOZWZpYWloiCycnJGYD5QwNjExMzUwNjIzNTMxNbYwNDA0NTE0QlZoFZOnF2@roKmho6QOAA)

Infix tacit function; can't handle the largest test case because of floating point representation.

Saved <s>1</s> 2 bytes thanks to @Adám!

<s>13 bytes added for the headers: `⎕IO←0`: **I**ndex **O**rigin = 0 and `⎕FR←1287`: **F**loat **R**epresentation = 128 bits.</s> (I'd forgotten that this [doesn't apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14232/43319))

#### How?

```apl
⊢⌷⍨∘⊂⊥⍣¯1⍨∘≢   ⍝ Tacit function, infix.
           ≢   ⍝ Tally (number of elements in) the right argument.
         ⍨∘    ⍝ Then swap the arguments of
     ⊥⍣¯1      ⍝ Base conversion (to base ≢<r_arg>)
    ⊂          ⍝ Enclose (convert to an array)
  ⍨∘           ⍝ Then swap the arguments of
 ⌷             ⍝ Index
⊢              ⍝ (Into) the right argument.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
s@LQjEl
```

Saved a byte thanks to hakr14 and another thanks to Mr. Xcoder.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%40LQjEl&input=%5B%22+%22%2C%22%5Cn%22%2C%22%7C%22%2C%22_%22%2C%22-%22%5D%0A1928149325670647244912100789213626616560861130859431492905908574660758972167966&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
s@LQjEl
    jElQ      Convert the second input (the number) to the appropriate base.
 @LQ          Look up each digit in the list of strings.
s             Add them all together.
```

Comment: Save a byte by replacing `m@Qd` with [`@LQ`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%40LQjszl&input=%5B%22+%22%2C%22%5Cn%22%2C%22%7C%22%2C%22_%22%2C%22-%22%5D%0A1928149325670647244912100789213626616560861130859431492905908574660758972167966&debug=0)

Comment: Save a byte by replacing `vz` with `E`.

Answer (score 2):

## Twig, 66 bytes

Created a `macro` that must be `import`ed into a template.

```
{%macro d(n,c)%}{%for N in n|split%}{{c[N]}}{%endfor%}{%endmacro%}
```

---

### Values expected:

For the first arguments (`n`):

- number
- string

For the second argument (`c`):

- Array of numbers
- Array of strings

---

### How to use:

- Create a `.twig` file
- Add `{% import 'file.twig' as uncompress %}`
- Call the macro `uncompress.d()`

### Ungolfed (non-functional):

```
{% macro d(numbers, chars) %}
    {% for number in numbers|split %}
        {{ chars[number] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

---

---

You can test this code on: https://twigfiddle.com/54a0i9

Answer (score 2):

## C89, limited-range signed `int n`, <s>64</s> 53 bytes

- changelog: take a `char **out` and modify it, instead of taking and returning a `char *`

Takes the number as an `int`, the lookup table as an array + length.
Output is written into a `char *outbuf`.  Caller passes (by reference) a pointer to the end of the buffer.  Function modifies that pointer to point to the first byte of the string on return.

```
g(n,I,B,O)char*I,**O;{for(**O=0;n;n/=B)*--*O=I[n%B];}
```

This is valid C89, and works correctly even with optimization enabled.  i.e. doesn't depend on gcc `-O0` behaviour when falling off the end of a non-void function or have any other UB.

Passing a pointer to the end of a buffer is normal for an optimized int->string function, such as [glibc's internal `_itoa`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/generic/_itoa.h.html#39).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) for a detailed explanation of breaking an integer into digits with a div / mod loop like we're doing here, in C as well as x86-64 asm.  If the base is a power of 2, you can shift/mask to extract digits MSD first, but otherwise the only good option is least-significant-digit first (with modulo).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRNb5tAEL3zK0aJ0gCF2E6rKJi6B/fQ@uRjD6kVLbDgVWGX7i5J3Mh/vXQG8FdaNSoHaz0fb2bevN00LNK0bQtXBotgHiy9dM20vwh8fxk/50q7eJiNYxnL0Wzu@WGIfxd38mK@irftPM67vNOs@cxYXXLpLrz4FQTHGflQTIE/1aVIhQ0xrbBrKJX63tRgWVLyAAZjzYzhGTADTCq75hqYLhzwIZ@CqP4FQCmATQlJ8SPHORc5jOHkw0YaWagyxxIPXBuhZBeKdiEtSJgB1gTZVAnXVJWsc7Qa8ZODymGB54QZTj6iA3yyCFk3tu/j4PCXO89INZYCcJLdfMkGNM@nFI0fdsGl1Zsp1Aor4tBWdY2UzFiMtV3tASVp8pzrq6PUJ2Gn8DI1F/oolyzjEN2VkMxiAz1R2N8pbMfcgxLZnqf7v6rGeXaoej8pISiD06JjR/PnU5Ibww26gaNh84hr5fDIyQpDMpalzAPWOD7d2773bpah6WGKIZl0uJOgs0tFLe4xB0USXK1V1qQcJv0MDLcDVlSoo4ynmle4D0I@qrXjd9cprbdHjp2tc85lJnKHVCfTssk4fDA2E@pq/fHUVIrkpY1mIJtDaquYkC4dUC1pMDCM54e7lTew3km1qbA@s0q4nXOy8uKjlfSKnEHnu17FzsGHPeOu76JoFcOfH1LDUtuwchAEyvRHI3pCQBi8c8V94koPsfHoYhveiA79a3Cg/bXPhygivEQUqH3VFGtaHy7h5n2YCEsz8oJuv8y6CwfXV/@B/ZVDpuSlxV@8HhZ3g1qsNU8FqTEm2ec4JmlQyXLTCdGIQmIUkUtPAgFVvDLcuj1jAVw@XQbYtvdCmSgMgxKn9jOeNEVxJMn9BenFgjBvo9t4eJt60RKHQf9QBPAGg3CR57ykN2bYNRJLT1D/3naBw66Lk1z0HgF0cqSgGuVlc/fswnyTZwH0/s6juW20xJvmbNv2JrqNJpP20xe2/JXmJStMGy7ftSFKdpbeRr8B).  Ungolfed version:

```
/* int n = the number
 * int B = size of I = base
 * char I[] = input table
 * char **O = input/output arg passed by ref:
 *    on entry: pointer to the last byte of output buffer.
 *    on exit:  pointer to the first byte of the 0-terminated string in output buffer
 */
void ungolfed_g(n,I,B,O)char*I,**O;
{
    char *outpos = *O;     /* Golfed version uses *O everywhere we use outpos */
    *outpos = 0;           /* terminate the output string */
    for(;n;n/=B)
        *--outpos = I[n%B]; /* produce 1 char at a time, decrementing the output pointer */
    *O = outpos;
}
```

In this explicit-length version, the input is a `char table[]` which does *not* need a terminating 0 byte, because we never treat it as a string.  It could be an `int table[]` for all we care.  C doesn't have containers that know their own length, so pointer+length is the normal way to pass an array with a size.  So we choose that instead of needing to `strlen`.

The maximum buffer size is approximately `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT + 1`, so it's small and compile-time constant.  (We use this much space with base=2 and all the bits set to 1.)  e.g. 33 bytes for 32 bit integers, including the `0` terminator.

---

## C89, signed `int`, table as an implicit-length C string, 65 bytes

```
B;f(n,I,O)char*I,**O;{B=strlen(I);for(**O=0;n;n/=B)*--*O=I[n%B];}
```

This is the same thing but the input is an implicit-length string so we have to find the length ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash + core utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 49 bytes

```bash
dc -e`echo -en $2|wc -c`o$1p|tr -dc 0-9|tr 0-9 $2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpLDsIwDAWvkkW3kWzHeY7vUolCqNRViwCJTe@emtW8zzzun22MZ095Xda@HcE9TXL@YunLMfHr/L5TDoGy/2Mg/jEGuzRWL1JhBDVRdRYmsubCBQIwKqiBuVCrriV0caoezRQgq81NGObAmElp3s9bvgA)

## Comments/explanation

This takes command-line arguments as input (the number in base 10, then a single string with the list of characters) and outputs to stdout. Special characters like space, newline, etc may be entered in octal notation (for example, `\040` for a space), or `\n` for a newline, `\t` for tab, or any other escape sequence that `echo -e` and `tr` interpret identically.

A lot of the bytes here are to handle special characters and larger test cases.  If I only have to handle non-terrible characters and the numbers are small (for example, the first test case), the following 24 bytes will do it:

```bash
dc -e${#2}o$1p|tr 0-9 $2
```

This uses parameter expansion `${#2}` to get the number of characters in the string, builds a dc program to do the base conversion, and then sends the converted number through `tr`.

This won't handle newlines or spaces or tabs, though, so to deal with escape sequences without affecting the base, I do a character count `wc -c` after interpreting the escapes with `echo -en`. This expands the program to 38 bytes:

```bash
dc -e`echo -en $2|wc -c`o$1p|tr 0-9 $2
```

Unfortunately, dc has an annoying "feature" where if it's outputting a large number, it will line wrap it with a slash+newline sequence, so the larger test cases have this extra output. To remove it, I pipe dc's output through `tr -dc 0-9` to remove non-numeric characters. And there we are.

Comment: I was going to suggest [`dc -e${#2}o$1p|tr 0-9 "$2"`](https://tio.run/##Dco9CgJBDAbQ3lMM67QDSSb5kpxG/AM7Re1cz57d8sG7nD@Pqtu1jXv/HeX/7Pxav@9GI9vSZakqTgnWnGJwgrqoJgsTeaTwhAAMAwWYJ4Wlzr1LkuUuV4DcIl0YnkC1w3oaGw) to take the input literally instead of in \escaped form so it *can* handle spaces, but `tr` doesn't have an option to not treat `-` as a range character, for example.  If the input has `-` not at one end of the string, it breaks.  Perhaps you can use `sed "y/0123456789/$2/"`.  No I guess not, GNU `sed` requires both args to `y` to be the same length, and it seems to choke on newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 17 bytes

```
{_[_2&ToBase!#_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BTsMwDIbvfYoQ0AQioNhJnGTSpAluHBCH3UoUVaVlk1A30d7GePXisMMs@ZNs//bvZpqadtvNvViuxHzMdcbFZv/UjN3VdU6n@bXrPsb65nBoP1NVvX3vhmnTjdMzC8b6@NXf59P6Zb8b1ovfXom6Ehw1equ5kD9SySxTUuc2xRAByqDlwZaz4dxfBBAxgI0GHXlN1qO1ERC09iEiGEIiIEc6EIDRwUVrWI5Ru8iVt0TauxA9AvlIVJwEO7wPjPMvSj5c7Iy15LRBPmmdCaDBWcCytZRK/K8J@ViQC1YFouCu4LZA8bUqpfkP)

### Explanation

```
{_[_2&ToBase!#_]}
{               }  ?? anonymous lambda; input: _ = dictionary, _2 = encoded
   _2&ToBase       ?? convert _2 to base
            !#_    ?? ... Size[_]
 _[            ]   ?? and take those members from the dictionary
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
τ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLPhCIsIiIsIlwiOlxcbi5fPSApKCxcIlxuMzQ0NjUwMzI2NTY0NTM4MTAxNTQxMiJd)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ÅвJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOuFTV7//yspKVlx6cXbKmhq6ADZXMYmJmamBsZGZqZmJqbGFoYGhqYmhkYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
n%|E@
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=n%25%7CE%40&i=%22%7C_%22+2740%0A%22chao%22+698911%0A%22+%5Cn%7C_-%22+1928149325670647244912100789213626616560861130859431492905908574660758972167966%0A%22%3A%5Cn._%3D+%29%28,%22+3446503265645381015412&m=2)

Explanation:

```
n%|E@ Full program, implicit input in order list, number
n%    Copy the list to the top and get its length
  |E  Convert the number to that base
    @ Map: index
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｌ┬｛╵⁸＠ｐ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjJDJXUyNTJDJXVGRjVCJXUyNTc1JXUyMDc4JXVGRjIwJXVGRjUw,i=JTVCJTIyJTIwJTIyJTJDJTIyJTVDbiUyMiUyQyUyMiU3QyUyMiUyQyUyMl8lMjIlMkMlMjItJTIyJTVEJTBBMTkyODE0OTMyNTY3MDY0NzI0NDkxMjEwMDc4OTIxMzYyNjYxNjU2MDg2MTEzMDg1OTQzMTQ5MjkwNTkwODU3NDY2MDc1ODk3MjE2Nzk2Ng__,v=3)

Straight forward implementation:

```
L┬{╵⁸@p
L      get the length of the input (popping the item)
 ┬     base decode the other input
  {    for each number there
   ╵     increment
    ⁸@   in the 1st input get that numbered item
      p  and output that
```

The input character set can be a string too as long as it doesn't contain a newline, because Canvas doesn't have a newline character & automatically converts it to a 2D object.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
l;A─{IaWp}
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=bCUzQkEldTI1MDAlN0JJYVdwJTdEZiUwQS4lMkMldTIxOTJm,inputs=MTkyODE0OTMyNTY3MDY0NzI0NDkxMjEwMDc4OTIxMzYyNjYxNjU2MDg2MTEzMDg1OTQzMTQ5MjkwNTkwODU3NDY2MDc1ODk3MjE2Nzk2NiUwQSUyMiUyMCU1Q24lN0NfLSUyMg__,v=0.12)

Pretty long, considering the idea is pretty much implemented in the language: [here](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/compression/index.html), entering

```
¶    __   __    ¶   |  |_|  |   ¶___|       |___¶-   -   -   -  ¶ - - - - - - - ¶- - - - - - - -¶_______________¶
```

gives out a compressed string using this method.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->n,b{n.to_s(b.size).tr"0-9",b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BbsIwDIbvfYooF2BKq9hxnBiJvUhXoXYa2g4riJbDoDx752rd4bPk3/5/@3rrfubTYS5fe9c9@mo8H4dtVw1f949dNV6tL8W67jnXNSbyztR2ss4ebdO4wtQsWQAW9V3VT6VVzusUBDOQBIycPFNCIgEE71MWhMDIDBzZZwYIPkehoOsoPop2iZh9ilkSAidhXs4YjX/rtfx94Wy53gpEHH1AzaMYMniIBLhY9v@WarUclCVnp2wVpxFN9d1ezGNqXTcVxpjLbRzMqdb2ZbNpimcx/wI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
:B
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3AB&i=1928149325670647244912100789213626616560861130859431492905908574660758972167966,+[%22+%22,%22%5Cn%22,%22%7C%22,%22_%22,%22-%22]%0A&a=1)

`:B` is an instruction in stax that does this.  It would normally operate on a "string"* instead of an array of "strings".  In the end, this means that the output is an array of single character arrays.  But output implicitly flattens anyway.

*Stax doesn't actually have a string type.  Text is represented by integer arrays of codepoints.

Comment: Huh, I never noticed this command ...

Comment: There are a lot.  I once added an instruction to stax that already existed, and I had just forgotten about. (array is non-descending?)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
]{~#@]#.inv[
```

### How?

```
      #.inv    convert
           [   the left argument (the number)      
   #@]         to base the length of the right argument (the list of characters)    
  {~           and use the digits as indices to
]              the list of characters
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsJADEX3/Yqgi1GoQ5LJZCaFguAfuBUpIpbqQheCCD5@vdbX8h4u5xz69lx7QKgA@/XtOZ6vx35/vKz6aTHy4NraOyjhUUF7LordtjsBJ0Fowd0b9wVq2YjeaNttTg6@NIhoxMAaVWLIhBSF@Pq@Va6ExbIE55sappPy5yHjTGKBoyZUSSxixISYsjEFZVUabJiVKGCOJmG4s2G0YSVRxRSzJSZNpvpJwT91b2YO@hc)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```
$n,$a=$args;$d=0;for(;$n-ne0){$n=[bigint]::DivRem($n,$a.count,[ref]$d);$s=$a[$d]+$s};$s
```

implicit using a .NET class [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger).

Test script:

```
$f = {
    $n,$a=$args;$d=0;for(;$n-ne0){$n=[bigint]::DivRem($n,$a.count,[ref]$d);$s=$a[$d]+$s};$s
}

@(
    @{
        n        = [bigint]::Parse("2740")
        ascii    = @("|", "_")
        expected = "_|_|_|__|_||"
    }
    @{
        n        = [bigint]::Parse("698911")
        ascii    = @("c", "h", "a", "o")
        expected = "aaaaaachoo"
    }
    @{
        n        = [bigint]::Parse("1928149325670647244912100789213626616560861130859431492905908574660758972167966")
        ascii    = @(" ", "`r`n", "|", "_", "-")
        expected = @"

    __   __    
   |  |_|  |   
___|       |___
-   -   -   -  
- - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -
_______________

"@
    }
    @{
        n        = [bigint]::Parse("3446503265645381015412")
        ascii    = @(":", "`r`n", ".", "_", "=", " ", ")", "(", ",")
        expected = @"
_===_
(.,.)
( : )
( : )
"@
    }
) | % {
    $r = &$f $_.n $_.ascii
    $r -eq $_.expected
    $r
}
```

output:

```
True
_|_|_|__|_||
True
aaaaaachoo
True

    __   __
   |  |_|  |
___|       |___
-   -   -   -
 - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
_______________

True
_===_
(.,.)
( : )
( : )
```

### Explanation

```
$n,$a=$args                # let $n is first argument (expected [bigint])
                           # let $a is second argument (expected char array)
$d=0                       # define variable $d to use as reference value
for(;$n-ne0){              # while bigint $n not equals 0
    $n=[bigint]::DivRem($n,$a.count,[ref]$d);
                           # .NET function DivRem returns the quotient of the division
                           # and place remainder to $d
                           # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem
    $s=$a[$d]+$s           # add a char to the string
}
$s                         # return string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

```
Outer[Part,{#},#2~IntegerDigits~Tr[1^#]+1,1]<>""&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xT8MwEIV3/4rIkapWGPCd7bMNFGVgYaIDWwhVVKVthgbJmCmkfz3YZLhPuvfe6d2ljefu0sb@0M7H7Xp@@4ldqHdtiGIsJ1Hi9XWI3akLL/2pj9/X91DDZ9ncgIDm6Znz1bx5ZLvQD7E@VlUpOOPN6r4aGRtH/ssF3/NJFGi1nESWDkk6p2nTfGWLvPMAi1kk8WNIWA4Fv80J8OhAe4WGrCRtUWsPCFJa5xEUIRGQIekIQElnvFYpjl4anzariaQ1zlsEsp5oqXrgovjvKvhdxj5jm1FkbDLWGSK/oLQmIxWmGm2UAwlGA06MTfMf)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 110 bytes

```c
char s[99],S[99];i;f(x,_)char*_;{i=strlen(_);*s=*S=0;while(x)sprintf(S,"%c%s",_[x%i],s),strcpy(s,S),x/=i;x=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZDRasMwDEXf8xUmELCCxpo9lAbhr8hjaoJnksbQucVKW4/Sb/firHoQF46udJH9OFmbkp1NENy3rcYud3I0yYgDZFAP9HSKl3AevRyAalZ1p3b0mN15lBH4GpxfJtlhWdmKSxz6WDmNDLia7PVXMnaA8VM5iorpldZx8WOcl1mYcLIotgT1qu@9huJZiLUy/TY8CiXMcnFyo40G2ui/w86ZZvClqdjAO05Z8dGXKCaZd@QLAO@JMC634MWOildK@/bQNk1@weUP)

Description:

```c
char s[99],S[99];           // Two strings, s and S (capacity 99)
i;                          // A variable to store the length of the string
f(x,_)char*_;{              // f takes x and string _
    i=strlen(_);            // set i to the length of _
    *s=*S=0;                // empty s and S
    while(x)                // loop until x is zero
        sprintf(S,"%c%s",   // print into S a character, then a string
                _[x%i],s),  // character is the x%i'th character of _, the string is s
        strcpy(s,S),        // copy S into s
        x/=i;               // divide x by the length of the string (and loop)
    x=s;}                   // return the string in s
```

Comment: If you start at the end of a buffer and work backwards, you can avoid `sprintf`.  [My C version is 53 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166708/ascii-art-uncompression-from-a-base-n-number/166831#166831), with the output buffer provided by the caller.  You could do one `strcpy` at the end if you want to copy the bytes to the start of a buffer.

Comment: That is brilliant. I don't care if its an awkward I/O format. Awkward I/O is C claim to fame! Well done, I'd recommend putting that into the C tips post.

Comment: Posted an answer on [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167273) explaining and justifying the technique.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
liq_,@\b\f=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCgJRDATQfk/hARQy@ckkUwgeZGFRQVC0sPfu3y0fvPvr@pnz/fxux8t6Wx/nOSFvhIYnyxjlEYLDrFqOQSfBpDWBYZ2KsXeXpXZVkFbZKgdL5HJYftvpDw) Takes input as the number, then a newline, then the characters in the ASCII art.

### Explanation

```
li           e# Read the first line and convert it to an integer
  q_,        e# Read the rest of the input and push its length n
     @\b     e# Convert the number to its base-n equivalent, as an array of numbers
        \f=  e# Map over the array, taking each element's index from the string
```

Comment: Since "IO is Flexible", I think you can get rid of the `liq` at the beginning, and that saves you 3 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 39 bytes

Port of [Rod's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166718/58974).

```
s=>g=n=>n?g(n/(l=s.length)|0)+s[n%l]:""
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoMwDADQuxQGCUOnP2MK0YMMP0ptqxISMWVfu3t97/A/b@Haz9KIrrEmqkZTJqFJ5gzyAiZrOUouG/47fNpXHryMztWgYsqxZc2QwIXNq0N4D5@h7xHrDQ)

Comment: Only works for `n` up to 64-bit, right?  (Python has arbitrary-precision integers built in, but JS numbers are naturally `double`-precision floats that can be converted to integer). Doesn't seem to work for the larger test cases in the question, like 1928149325670647244912100789213626616560861130859431492905908574660758972167966.  Oh, but the question allows answers like that.  Still, should be noted.

Answer (score 1):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 86 bytes

Wow, this was a huge challenge!

This was made hard due to the lack of direct access to specific indexes when the index is a variable.
A bug also made it longer, requiring to store the values inside a variable.

```
{@setA argv.1}{@eachargv.0}{@setC C,"{@echoA.",_,"}"}{@calljoin intoC"",C}{@/}{@evalC}
```

---

### Values expected:

The first argument (`argv.0`) can be:

- An integer
- A string with numbers
- An array of integers

The second argument (`argv.1`) can be:

- A string
- An array

### How this works?

It works this way:

- Cycles through the number/string passed as the first argument
- Sets the variable `C` to be an array containing:

  - The previous value `C`
  - The string `"{@echoA."`
  - The value of the loop
  - The string `"}"`
- Joins everything together (using PHP's `join` function)
  This results in, for example, `C` containing `"{@echoA.0}{@echoA.1}..."`
- Evaluates the result of `C`

### Ungolfed:

```
{@set args argv.1}
{@each argv.0 as number}
    {@set code code, "{@echo args.", number , "}"}
    {@call join into code "", code}
{@/}
{@eval code}
```

---

You can try this code on: https://ideone.com/NEKl2q

---

#### Optimal result

If there weren't bugs, this would be the best result, accounting for the limitations (77 bytes):

```
{@eachargv.0}{@setC C,"{@echoargv.1.",_,"}"}{@calljoin intoC"",C}{@/}{@evalC}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32 bytes

```perl6
{$^a.base($^b).comb>>.&{$b[$_]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7dTsMwDIXveYooqpZWClHsOE7MtL3I2Kp2GgLEVsSu0Nizl4Sfq134k61z7OP3w8cbz8dPtXhSKzVfmt3gxuF8aJvd2Ln9dBzXa7e4NOOm6bfX67w8D9XbYiJv1UZ/aat7ve3c6/RyWt79qSxZAKq@L/pzqaHUdOMDwQwkASMnz5SQSADB@5QFITAyA0f2mQGCz1EoFDuKj1KmRMw@xSwJgZMw10BVgh5PBb@fWX1/kxqIOPqA5TLFkMFDJMCybB6MVT/byrjSmr5iVaEquoq2wpr/o/M3)

Anonymous code block that take an integer and a list of characters and returns a list of characters.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                              }  #Anonymous code block
 $^a.base($^b)                    #Convert number to base (len(list))
              .comb               #Convert number to list of characters
                   >>             #Map each character to
                     .&{$b[$_]}   #To the index of that character in the list
```